# How to isolate terminal on WebStorm 2019.3

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In WebStorm 2018.3.5 when I press Up key it suggests me the last command I ran on this exact tab.
On WebStorm 2019.3.1 when I run a command on other tab or run something from system terminal and open a new tab and press Up it suggests me the last actual command ran on the system not in current tab.
Is there any way to configure it to have its own commands history in the latest WebStorm version?
OS I am currently running is Linux Mint 18 and using zsh as a shell.
Thanks.